# Neo4j takes long time to create relations among nodes

Tags: java, neo4j

I have made a simple java code to make relations among more than 600 thousand existing nodes, the relation data is taken from 1 million rows, the problem is it takes almost forever to finish creating relations, only 7930 relations are created at the moment of writing this post.

How this problem could be solved?

```
public void createRealtionBetweenNodes(Postgresql object){

 Map<Integer, String[][]> data = object.getRelationData();

try (Driver driver = org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic( "user", "password" ) );
                Session session = driver.session()){

for(int incrementer: data.keySet()){

String [][] dataholder = data.get(incrementer);

session.run( "match (x:Node{id:{id1}}),(y:Node{id:{id2}}) create (x)-[:Knows{ID:{KID}}]->(y);", parameters("id1",dataholder[0][0],"id2",dataholder[0][1],"KID",dataholder[0][2]));

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: share sample of input and your code

Comment: I've updated my code @TomažBratanič

Comment: Not sure how anyone can answer this for you: We have no idea how long your reads take from Postgres, and if that's the bottleneck (have you run your code without inserting into neo, and just reading from postgres?). We have no idea what type of hardware or VM you're using, or if your two databases are sharing the same environment. We have no idea how long each insert is taking (your code doesn't measure anything). And "as of this writing," we have no idea how long you've been sitting around waiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess,based on the data you provide, that Node.id is not indexed. If it's not, and there are a lot of Node nodes, database hits could be a lot until it matches the id. Try creating an index and running this again.

Comment: `create index on :Node(id)` or better `create constraint on (n:Node) assert n.id is unique`

Comment: Your solution has solved my problem, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You should also not create a *Driver* and *Session* per insert. But rather keep them and create a transaction per 10k to 100k relationships.

Also to speed this up further, have a look here: 
http://jexp.de/blog/2017/03/5-tips-tricks-for-fast-batched-updates-of-graph-structures-with-neo4j-and-cypher/